# PowerApps change dropdown value based on text box value

Tags: forms, canvas, drop-down-menu, powerapps, textinput

I have created a form in the Power Apps Canvas app. I have added Title (Text input) and Courses (Dropdown control). My requirement is that if I add a Title to the text input, then The dropdown value will be changed based on the title.

[image]

Please suggest any solution

Comment: I don't understand your requirements.  In your second screen how do the Titles related to the Courses?

Answer (score 0):

Say these controls are called TextInput1 and DropDown1. Set TextInput1's Default property to DropDown1.Selected.Value

Depending on the data source you set to DropDown1, you may have to use a specific field name instead of .Value